# How to pass structures to functions whose parameter type has two asterisks

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, arguments

Let there be a structure called Employee :

```
struct Employee
{
    int basicsalary;
    int bonus;
    int netsalary;
};
```

Let there be a function prototype as follows :

```
int calc_NetSalary(struct Employee**,int);
```

Let the variable for an array of structures be declared in main function as follows :

```
struct Employee emp[100];
```

Let the function be called in main as follows :

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    emp[i].netsalary = calc_NetSalary(emp[i],n);    // Warning is here
}
```

Let the function definition be as follows :

```
int calc_NetSalary(struct Employee** emp,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        emp[i]->netsalary = emp[i]->basicsalary + emp[i]->bonus;
    }
    return emp[i]->netsalary;
}
```

I don't know what to pass as an argument to the function that expects a parameter with two asterisks (in place of `emp` above). I am getting a warning as `passing argument 1 of ‘calc_NetSalary’ from incompatible pointer type`. I know it must be a silly mistake I did or I am not clear about the concepts of pointers. Please help !

Comment: `parameter type has two asterisks`....run, grab a book a start reading it.

Comment: You *do* know what an asterisk in a declaration means? Perhaps you should get a couple of [good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read more about *pointers*?

Comment: and do not use markup in pre-formatted blocks.

Comment: Were you given these definitions, or are you trying to work this out for yourself?

Comment: I was very confused by what the heck does `Emp* **emp**` means

Comment: ** emp **, are you inventing a new language (C, C++, C# and now ** C **) ??

Comment: @RyanB. No, just trying to use bold within a code block.

Comment: When passing the array `emp` as a function parameter, it will decay to a pointer to the first element, which will be of type `struct Employee*`. So the current function parameter type of `struct Employee**` doesn't make much sense here. Perhaps it is a mistake in the exercise. Ask your supervisor.

Comment: Do you store the result of the whole array as a member of a single element?

Comment: This is a kind of test where the function prototype has to be written as it is. Please tell me what should I put in the first argument of function call so that the type of argument it expects is matched

Comment: @RahulPakhare That depends entirely on what the function does with it.

Comment: I have added the function code... please take a look

Comment: So the function in question seems to expect an array of *pointers* to `struct Employee`: `struct Employee * pemp[100];`

Comment: `void calc_netsalary(struct Employee *emp, int n){ int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        emp[i].netsalary = emp[i].basicsalary + emp[i].bonus;
    }
}` and Call `calc_netsalary(emp, n);`

Comment: or `int calc_netsalary(struct Employee *emp){ return emp->basicsalary + emp->bonus; }` and Call `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    emp[i].netsalary = calc_NetSalary(&emp[i]);
}` in this case
You can set within function without setting a return value.

Comment: or `int calc_netsalary(struct Employee emp){ return emp.basicsalary + emp.bonus; }` and Call `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    emp[i].netsalary = calc_NetSalary(emp[i]);
}` in this case
You can't set within function. You must use return values.

Comment: @RahulPakhare: The conditions you have been given do not make sense.  The `calc_netSalary` function expects an array of *pointers* to `struct Employee`, but you've been told to declare `emp` as an array of `struct Employee`.  It's not just a matter of mismatched types, the *structure* of the data that `calc_netSalary` expects does not match the structure of `emp` in `main`.  There's no way you can bash `emp` into the shape that `calc_netSalary` expects.  Ask your instructor/supervisor if that's what they really meant.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY typo. sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on my comment:

The `calc_netSalary` function expects the data in `emp` to be laid out like this:

```
     +---+                 +-------------+-------+-----------+
emp: |   | emp[0] -------> | basicsalary | bonus | netsalary |
     +---+                 +-------------+-------+-----------+
     |   | emp[1] ----+
     +---+            |    +-------------+-------+-----------+
     |   | emp[2] -+  +--> | basicsalary | bonus | netsalary |
     +---+         |       +-------------+-------+-----------+
      ...          |      
                   |       +-------------+-------+-----------+ 
                   +-----> | basicsalary | bonus | netsalary |
                           +-------------+-------+-----------+
```

That is, each `emp[i]` is a *pointer* to an instance of `struct Employee`.

However, your declaration of `emp` in `main` looks like this:

```
     +-------------+-------+-----------+
emp: | basicsalary | bonus | netsalary | emp[0]
     +-------------+-------+-----------+
     | basicsalary | bonus | netsalary | emp[1]
     +-------------+-------+-----------+
     | basicsalary | bonus | netsalary | emp[2]
     +-------------+-------+-----------+
      ...
```

That is, each `emp[i]` is an *instance* of `struct Employee`.

Either the declaration of `emp` in `main` is wrong, or the definition of `calc_netSalary` is wrong; they *cannot* be made to work together.  To make `emp` in `main` match up with what `calc_netSalary` expects, it needs to be declared an initialized in one of the following ways:

```
struct Employee **emp = malloc( sizeof *emp * 100 );
if ( emp )
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    emp[i] = malloc( sizeof *emp[i] );
```

or

```
struct Employee *emp[100];
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  emp[i] = malloc( sizeof *emp[i] );
```

If `emp` is really supposed to be declared as an array of `struct Employee`, then the `calc_netSalary` function needs to be changed as follows:

```
int calc_netSalary(struct Employee* emp,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        emp[i].netsalary = emp[i].basicsalary + emp[i].bonus;
    }
    return emp[i].netsalary;
}
```

If you were told to declare `emp` as an array of `struct Employee` and figure out a way to pass it to `calc_netSalary` such that it would be treated as an array of *pointers* to `struct Employee`, then you were given an impossible task.  Something is deeply wrong with the assignment.

**Edit**

Actually, there is a third way around this, but it involves declaring a second array in `main` and passing *that* as the argument:

```
struct Employee emp[100];
struct Employee *emp2[100];
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  emp2[i] = &emp[i];
...
calc_netSalary( emp2, 100 );
```

but I'm assuming the assignment requires you to use `emp`.

Comment: The function prototype of calc_NetSalary has to be as specified. The declaration of emp can be tweaked to match to the function's requirements.

Comment: @RahulPakhare: Then `emp` needs to be declared as an array of pointers, and each element needs to be initialized to point to an instance of `struct Employee`.

Comment: BTW `return emp[i].netsalary;` occurs out of bounds.

Comment: Did you draw this by hand or is there some tool to generate ASCII memory drawings?

Comment: @RyanB.: Drew it by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Because the use of `calc_NetSalary` is unclear, the following is one possible scenario.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Employee{
    int basicsalary;
    int bonus;
    int netsalary;
};

//This prototype can not be changed!!
//OK, But What kind of use is it?
int calc_NetSalary(struct Employee**, int);

//One scenario

void make_employee(struct Employee **emp, int n);

int main(void){
    struct Employee *emp;
    int n = 100;//It is decided at runtime by user input or something..

    make_employee(&emp, n);
    //.. basicsalary and bonus are determined..
    if(calc_NetSalary(&emp, n))
        puts("done..");
    free(emp);
}

void make_employee(struct Employee **emp, int n){
    *emp = calloc(n, sizeof(struct Employee));
}

int calc_NetSalary(struct Employee** emp,int n){
    if(n < 1 || *emp == NULL)
        return 0;//return false;//Inoperable

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        (*emp)[i].netsalary = (*emp)[i].basicsalary + (*emp)[i].bonus;
    }
    return 1;//normal end
}
```